# Building a Python Module Problem

Tags: 10.04, python, compiling, symbolic-link

I am having the following issue and am not sure how to fix. I do not know what linking is but I hear it's related to the problem.

I'm trying to set up a python module:

First I call in the directory where setup.py exists:

```
python setup.py install
```

and then I get the following error:

```
cannot find -lboost_python-mt-py26
```

I'm pretty sure I have boost. How can I link it?

Comment: Do you have _libboost-python-dev_ installed?

Comment: I believe so, I needed it for another package. How would I be able to check?

Comment: Run `dpkg -l libboost-python-dev`. Also, please specify what version of Ubuntu you are on in the question (add the version as a tag).

Comment: I don't have it. How would I install it such that running install would always find it?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev` ? That should work.

Comment: Yes, that would install it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21686/discussion-between-alvarezcl-and-dobey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the *libboost-python-dev* package. You can install it by running:

`sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev`